# Please confirm the best way to Restore the DC when a custom Pen and a custom Brush are selected

Tags: c++, winapi, wm-paint

Can someone confirm if [this sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/setting-the-pen-or-brush-color) from Microsoft fails to restore the custom brush set with `SetDCBrushColor`?

```
    case WM_PAINT:        
        {    
            hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        //    Initializing original object
            HGDIOBJ original = NULL;
        //    Saving the original object
            original = SelectObject(hdc,GetStockObject(DC_PEN));

        //    ...

            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(BLACK_PEN));
            Rectangle(hdc,0,0,200,200);

            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
            SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
            SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(255,0,0));
            SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(0,0,255));
            Rectangle(hdc,100,300,200,400);
            SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(0,255,0));
            Rectangle(hdc,300,150,500,300);

        //   Restoring the original object
            SelectObject(hdc,original);
        }
        
        break;
//...
```

Paul Watt, and other posters, suggest we use `SelectObject` to restore changes to the pen and brush separately, or that we use `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC`.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/224754/Guide-to-Win32-Memory-DC

```
// Setup paint for first layer.
HGDIOBJ hOldBrush = ::SelectObject(hDC, hBrush);
HGDIOBJ hOldPen   = ::SelectObject(hDC, hPen);
HGDIOBJ hOldFont  = ::SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
HGDIOBJ hOldMan   = ::SelectObject(hDC, hBmp);

// ... Paint a motley display

::SelectObject(hDC, hOldBrush);
::SelectObject(hDC, hOldPen);
::SelectObject(hDC, hOldFont);
::SelectObject(hDC, hOldMan);
```

Or use `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC` to make it easy:

```
// Take a snap-shot of the current state of the DC
//https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-savedc
  int SaveDC(
    __in HDC hdc,           // Handle to the DC
);

// Restore the DC to a previously saved state
int RestoreDC(
    __in HDC hdc,           // Handle to the DC
    __in int nSavedDC       // Saved state claim ticket
);
```

I realize that I need to use `DeleteObject` on any brushes/pens I create that are not stock objects.

Did Microsoft forget to use `SelectObject` with a previously saved version of the original brush? (Or should Microsoft have used `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Did Microsoft forget to use SelectObject with a previously saved
> version of the original brush?*

I would say: Yes, they did!

In the case of the `SetDCPenColor` call, there isn't a problem, as restoring the original (saved) pen will revert the changes made. It seems that the example forgets to save (and subsequently restore) the original brush; if this is a custom brush, then simply restoring the brush colour with `SetDCBrushColor` would (IMHO) not be sufficient restoration.

But the issue doesn't end there! The linked example has also 'forgotten' to call `EndPaint`! From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-beginpaint):

> Each call to **BeginPaint** must have a corresponding call to the [EndPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-endpaint)
> function.

---

> *Or should Microsoft have used SaveDC and RestoreDC?*

For both convenience and code safety, I would say this is the best policy: saving and restoring the *entire* DC state(s) avoids any issues that may later arise if/when additional changes to the DC are made in future code revisions. Bracketing your code in `SaveDC()` and `RestoreDC()` calls also has the advantage of restoring font colours, text modes, mapping modes, *et cetera*.

However, for code that may possibly be executed extremely frequently, saving and restoring only the components you actually change may show performance improvements (especially on older or slower processors).